# Custom-made Python module cannot be found or imported

Tags: python, module, package, pycharm

I am creating a very simple function called `BMICalculator`. So I created a folder called `testmodule`. In it are three files: the `BMICalculator.py`, `setup.py` and an empty `README.txt`.

The `BMICalculator.py` reads as follows:

```
def body_mass_index(weight: float, height_in_metres: float) -> int:
    """Calculates the Body Mass Index (BMI) and rounds off the result to zero decimal places"""
    result = round(weight / (height_in_metres**2), 2)  # Round off the result
    print(result)
```

The `setup.py` file reads as follows:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name='BMICalculator',
    version='2.0',
    description="Calculates your Body Mass Index (BMI)",
    author="Samuel Gachuhi",
    author_email="xxx@xxx.com",
    py_modules=['BMICalculator']
)
```

So to create the distribution file I run the following code using Windows Powershell.

```
PS D:\gachuhi\Pycharm\...\testmodule> py -3 setup.py sdist
```

Results:

```
...
copying BMICalculator.egg-info\PKG-INFO -> BMICalculator-2.0\BMICalculator.egg-info
copying BMICalculator.egg-info\SOURCES.txt -> BMICalculator-2.0\BMICalculator.egg-info
copying BMICalculator.egg-info\dependency_links.txt -> BMICalculator-2.0\BMICalculator.egg-info
copying BMICalculator.egg-info\top_level.txt -> BMICalculator-2.0\BMICalculator.egg-info
Writing BMICalculator-2.0\setup.cfg
creating dist
Creating tar archive
removing 'BMICalculator-2.0' (and everything under it)
```

The last message showed the process was successful. A `dist` and `egg-info` file were created in my `testmodule` folder. Final step was to install the package using `Pip` via Powershell.

```
PS D:\gachuhi\Pycharm\head_first_python\testmodule\dist> py -3 -m pip install BMICalculator-2.0.tar.gz
```

Result:

```
Processing d:\gachuhi\pycharm\...\testmodule\dist\bmicalculator-2.0.tar.gz
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for BMICalculator, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: BMICalculator
  Attempting uninstall: BMICalculator
    Found existing installation: BMICalculator 2.0
    Uninstalling BMICalculator-2.0:
      Successfully uninstalled BMICalculator-2.0
  Running setup.py install for BMICalculator ... done
Successfully installed BMICalculator-2.0
```

This shows my package was installed successfully. However, when I search for it in any Pycharm program using `import BMICalculator` or even `from BMICalculator import body_mass_index` the Pycharm response is `No module named 'BMICalculator'. I thought a source distribution file can be found by a programme running from any location in the computer but this is not the case here.

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I finally cracked the solution. You see, I use Pycharm for all Python code because it works like a charm. The reason my package could not be found when I open a Python programme in a different directory is because Pycharm needs to install packages into its own system first. That is, to install any package in Pycharm, even if you could have installed it using base Python interpreter, in Pycharm this is the process:
`Settings>Project>Python Interpreter` and click the `+` to install the package.

Now in my post I had successfully created the source distribution file. However, to make it work in Pycharm, that is, installing a local package into Pycharm, this is the process:
`View>Tool Windows>Python Packages>Add Package>From Disk`. Inside the `Install Package` dialog box, select the `Path` to your **module folder**, not the `sdist` file. ie the `testmodule` folder as in my case. If you had created the distribution file well, there should be no problem with Pycharm installing the package inside the module folder successfully. See -- https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/installing-uninstalling-and-upgrading-packages.html#install=package-from-disc

Answer (score -1):

if testmodule folder is not python directory, create a python file named **init** in testmodule and then try import.

Comment: Hello, I've followed your advice, much like this article here -- https://www.webucator.com/article/how-to-create-a-python-package/. However, when I run the `body_mass_index` function as in after this code `from testmodule import body_mass_index` I only get values - 0.0. This is despite me crosschecking the code in the function